# Html.fromHtml not working with bold text in body while share intent in email

Tags: java, android, html, css, fromhtml

```
String mailContent = "<b>boldText:</b>"
```

I tried below also but not working.

```
String mailContent = "<strong>boldText:</strong>"
```

Email intent.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/html");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
getResources().getString(R.string.slide3_text1));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(mailContent));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

Please check this code not showing bold text in mail.
i want to display like below.

**Title of Content:**

Name

etc...

**Title of Content 2:**

Name

etc.

Please take look into this and let me know I read many blogs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: THe email app is a completely different app.  There's no way to force it to display HTML.  It may not even be capable of it.  I'm not certain whether styling in spannables is kept when sending data via an Intent.  My guess is it isn't.

Comment: fromHtml() is just for your own app TextView's not sure that the shared text will work in every app

Comment: @AkshayPaliwal yes but need to make sure because in other blogs they have written its possible please check this same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741128/make-text-bold-italic-and-bigger-for-email-body-in-java
https://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/05/17/sending-html-email-with-android-intent/

Comment: If you want bold text on Whatsapp then follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57604994/8360050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per R&D, I found that this is not possible in new Gmail because Gmail introduces own editor in the mail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Constant Value: "android.intent.extra.HTML_TEXT"` along with `EXTRA_TEXT`

Comment: or you can do as ' Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder().append("<b>this is bold</br>").toString)'  modify this code as it have some silly errors but it will work   also use Intent yourintent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));

Comment: sendIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.HTML_TEXT", Html.fromHtml(mailContent)); this way not working.

Comment: sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder().append("<b>this is bold</br>").toString())); this way is also not working

Comment: have  you used Intent yourintent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));

Comment: Not yet, i want to write in the body using this we can set mailto only.
i dont know how to set body in your code.

Comment: use this emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
          "Email Body");

Comment: As per R&D, I found that this is not possible in new Gmail because Gmail introduces own editor in the mail. 
Thanks