# Unable to get "Bold" HTML text in email composer in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to implement email compose in the Android app using Kotlin, I want HTML formatted text in email compose. I don't know for what reason I am not getting Bold text even using  tags. Just an FYI my 
 tag is working properly. Please help me out with this. Following is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)enter code here
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Invite")
 intent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml(StringBuilder()
                .append("<b>Hello!</b> <br/><br/>")
                .append("<b>Welcome to the app!</b> <br/>")
                .toString())
 )
```

Comment: Maybe you should put `<html>` before `<b>Hello...`, and close with `</html>`? BTW, newline in HTML is `<br />`

Comment: No <html>......</html> is not working.

Comment: Have a look here, a lot of people seem to be suggesting Gmail doesn't support this anymore.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113165/html-fromhtml-not-working-with-bold-text-in-body-while-share-intent-in-email

Comment: Have you tried concatenating strings in place of `StringBuilder`?